# Guest book does not appear to be saving data?

Tags: discussion, bug, time-travel-mode

The new Guest Book seems like a nice idea, but it doesn't appear to be saving any data entered into it. Entered text appears immediately upon submitting the form on the current page via JavaScript, but the data does not seem to be posting anywhere and does not survive a page reload.

There's a new JavaScript object called XMLHttpRequest (now standard with Internet Explorer 5) which might allow us to post the form data asynchronously without the need for reloading the entire page, but I haven't had a chance to experiment with it yet.

Maybe the devs can look into it?

[image]

Comment: It's not an actual chat box; all messages you see there are fake and not actually transmitted anywhere. See [Why does the guestbook chatbox not produce any network activity?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/326018/why-does-the-guestbook-chatbox-not-produce-any-network-activity)

Comment: Yeah, all the text repeats. I got fooled as well. Though, an actual public chat box would be a good idea. Or not. ‮

Comment: @SonictheWizardWerehog read the question again; the author is clearly in on the joke.  "Now standard with Internet Explorer 5" should tip you off.

Comment: @Mr.YouKnowWhoIAm https://chat.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MonicaCellio That seemed more like a side note to me, as in "this feature has been present for a long time, why aren't you using it?". Overall, it seemed to me as if the author were honestly asking about this.

Comment: This site was built for Netscape 3 (see the copyright footer), and [Netscape doesn't support `XMLHttpRequest`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7673204/8828658).